# Find max and min values in a WPF DataGrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that is bound to a list of objects.
The data being displayed is basically a table of flight arrivals & departures by each hour of the day.

The XAML for the datagrid is:

```
 <DataGrid Name="TrafficGrid" Margin="20,10,10,0"  Grid.Row="1" Height="550"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Background="Beige" RowBackground="Beige"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectionUnit="Cell">
 </DataGrid>
```

The object declaration is:

```
public class fltgridCell
        {
            public int cellValue { get; set; }
            public int highlight { get; set; }
        }
```

The list declaration is:

```
public List<fltgridRow> fltrowsList = new List<fltgridRow>();

 public class fltgridRow
        {
            public string hour { get; set; }
            public fltgridCell cmclDep { get; set; } = new fltgridCell() {cellValue = 0, highlight = 0};
            public fltgridCell cmclArr { get; set; } = new fltgridCell( ) { cellValue = 0, highlight = 0 };
            public fltgridCell corpDep { get; set; } = new fltgridCell( ) { cellValue = 0, highlight = 0 };
            public fltgridCell corpArr { get; set; } = new fltgridCell( ) { cellValue = 0, highlight = 0 };
            public fltgridCell gaDep { get; set; } = new fltgridCell( ) { cellValue = 0, highlight = 0 };
            public fltgridCell gaArr { get; set; } = new fltgridCell( ) { cellValue = 0, highlight = 0 };
         }
```

After I retrieve the count of each type of flight from the database and populate fltrowsList , I bind to the grid:
    TrafficGrid.ItemsSource = fltrowsList;

I want to find the max and min values for each class of flight, and then highlight those two cells in the column. However, I am stumped as to how to iterate through each column of the datagrid and find the max and min values.  Have tried several approaches similar to the following (iterate down a column), but none work.

```
for ( nCol = 1; nCol < 13; nCol++ )
{
    for ( nRow = 0; nRow < 24; nRow++ )
    {
         var rr = TrafficGrid.Columns[nCol].GetCellContent(TrafficGrid.CurrentCell(nRow) );
```

etc.

Maybe I am not thinking of this in the right way.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a highlight property in your cell class, you could determine the min and max value before. Take the database result an do a LINQ query like `var fClassMax = databaseResult.Max( t => t.flightClass)` and `var fClassMin = databaseResult.Min( t => t.flightClass)`, then you have the values and need the set the hightlight property the where the values matches.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion.  I will try it and report.  However, I will be traveling a bit, so it may be a few days before I post the reply.